# Stopping a timer in componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm making a little countdown timer as a React exercise (for myself, not a class or anything) and everything works fine (although notes are always welcome) except that I noticed that it keeps counting down even after the component is unmounted.

So now I want to make it stop on unmount, but can't seem to get it right.  What is the protocol for stopping `setInterval` on unmount?  Here's what I have:

```
class TimerVal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      timeToGo: 30
    }
  }
  secondsToMMSS(seconds) {
    //returns "mm:ss"
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(
      () => this.setState({
        timeToGo: this.state.timeToGo - 1
      }),
      1000
    )
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    () => this.setState({
      timeToGo: undefined
    })
  }
  render() {
    // styles
    console.log(this.state)
    const count = ( this.state.timeToGo > 0 ) ? this.secondsToMMSS(this.state.timeToGo) : "00:00"
    console.log(count)
    return(
      <div style={timerStyle}>
        <span style={timerSpanStyle}>
          {count}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few things. First of all, this isn't doing anything:

```
() => this.setState({
  timeToGo: undefined
})
```

You're just defining an anonymous function and doing nothing with it. Next, don't just set `timeToGo` to undefined when the countdown stops. The interval will just keep on going. Instead, clear the interval:

```
this.interval = setInterval(
  () => this.setState({
    timeToGo: this.state.timeToGo - 1
  }),
  1000
)
```

Then in `componentWillUnmount`:

```
clearInterval(this.interval)
```

This will cleanly clear the countdown. Finally, clear the interval when the countdown reaches 0, or else it will keep running. That costs resources:

```
this.interval = setInterval(
  () => {
    if(this.state.timeToGo > 0) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        timeToGo: prevState.timeToGo - 1
      }))
    } else {
      clearInterval(this.interval)
    }
  },
  1000
)
```

This will clear the interval once it reaches 0. Also, note that I used `prevState`. Since `setState` is asynchronous this ensures that it's accessing the correct state.

Comment: Any idea how to do the same for functional components?

Answer (score 0):

I have another option that you could use

**First:** In constructor add a variable **idInterval** to the state  and add a function **setTimeout**

```
this.state = {  timeToGo: 30, idInterval: 0}
setTimeout( ()=>clearInterval(this.state.id),this.state.timeToGo)
```

**Second:** set a variable idInterval with the new reference, And That is it. Bytes!!!

```
ComponentDidMount() {
   const id2 = setInterval(
      ()=>(
          this.setState( {timeToGo : this.state.timeToGo -1}), 
          this.setState( {idInterval:  id2})
          ),
      1000
    )
 }
```